# How to find the terms in n th power of this matrix?

Tags: matrices

The Matrix Being :
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}

I need to find the terms in n th power of this  matrix .
I tried multiplying it for a few terms the pattern was hard for me to grasp !
How can I find these terms ?

Comment: Did you mean the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}
$$
by any chance?

Comment: @AlecTeal I can show you what I computed but it is totally waste! I have written it "I tried multiplying it for a few terms the pattern was hard for me to grasp ". I googled this and found out some irrelevant  results too ! So does telling what I have done is important really? + This is not at all homework! -_- I do not do homework!!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma While it's not always useful to show one's work, in your case, you could at least write down the first few powers of the matrix to convince the others that you have indeed "tried multiplying it for a few terms the pattern was hard for me to grasp". Yet an answer below shows that the **square** of the matrix is already a multiple of the identity matrix. So, to me, your claim is totally unconvincing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$ and
$A^2=(a^2 + b^2) \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

So $$A^{2k}=(a^2 + b^2)^k\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$A^{2k + 1}=A^{2k}A=(a^2 + b^2)^k\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Take 
$$
A = \pmatrix{a&b\\b&-a}
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, as we can note using the trace and determinant. Define $\alpha = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for convenience.  Assume that $\alpha \neq 0$, in which case the answer is obvious.

We note that the matrix
$$
M = \frac 1{\alpha} A
$$
has eigenvalues $\pm 1$.  It follows that 
$$
M^2 = I = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
so that $M^{n}$ switches between $I$ and $M$. We can then conclude that
$$
A^n = (\alpha M)^n = \alpha^nM^n
$$
which is to say that
$$
A^n = 
\begin{cases}
\alpha^n \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} & n \text{ is even}\\
\alpha^{n-1} \pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a} & n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: $m$ or $\alpha$? that's the problem :D

Comment: @the_candyman for me, $M$ is usually a matrix, and $m$ is usually an integer.

Comment: sorry man, I was not clear. You wrote "...$\alpha = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for convenience. Assume that $m \neq 0...$", maybe it is a typo. You meant $\alpha \neq 0$, right?

Comment: Ha! I was choosing between $M$ and $\alpha$ and wrote $m$. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the diagonalization of your matrix $A$. In particular, you can found $$A = T D T^{-1},$$ where $D$ is diagonal and contains all eigenvalues of matrix $A$, while $T$'s columns are the eigenvectors of your matrix $A$.

Using this form, then:

$$A^n = T D^n T^{-1},$$

which can be really easy to compute.

In your case:

$$T = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{a-m}{b} & \frac{a+m}{b}\\1 & 1\end{array}\right]$$

and

$$D =  \left[\begin{array}{cc}-m & 0 \\ 0 & m \end{array}\right],$$

having posed $m = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

In this case, you have that:

$$D^n = \left[\begin{array}{cc}(-m)^n & 0 \\ 0 & m^n \end{array}\right]$$

**Why this work**

Look at equation $A = T D T^{-1}$. Then:

$$A^n = T D T^{-1} \cdot T D T^{-1} \cdot T D T^{-1} \cdots T D T^{-1} = \\
= T D (T^{-1} T) D (T^{-1} T) D (T^{-1} \cdots T) D T^{-1} = \\
= T D I D I D I \cdots I D T^{-1} = \\
= T D^n T^{-1}$$